# Is there a way I can make a parameter have a default with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

> Blockquote

Here's my function:

```
networkStart = (action: any) => {
    this.action = action;
    this.net = true;
    this.netd = true;
}
```

How can I make it so that action defaults to 'default' if there is no action specified?  Also how can I create an interface for this function that allows me to call it with or without the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an interface and other ambient things you cannot specify the `default` value that is used i.e. you can :

```
declare function foo(hasDefault?:any);

foo();
```

but not `hasDefault = 'default'`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default value using the equals sign next to your parameter.

```
networkStart = (action: any = 'default') => {
    this.action = action;
    this.net = true;
    this.netd = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and set my interface like this:  networkStart: (action: string) => void;  But when I call the function with no parameters I get a syntax error in Visual Studio. Is there some way I need to define the interface differently if there is a default ?